# Clear Options and Re-Populate the Dropdown List - jQuery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

**Question:** How to clear options list and then re-populate?

Description: When a event fires, I need to wipe out the current contents of the drop down list of #regionlist and #citylist.

Problem: once user submits the form via GET method. Region list and city list values get accumulated (new cities + the previous list of cities (before refresh)).

***The code below populates the lists, how can i clear the list before populating the list***

```
function getRegions(e){//search regions from databse using ajax and jquery
    if(e!=''){
        $.post("library/region.php", {ids: e },
           function(data){
            $("#regionlist").html(data.regions); 
           if(data.cities){//if region not exists show the cities 
             $("#citylist").html(data.cities);
            } 
        }, "json");
    }   
}
function getCities(e){//search cities from databse using ajax and jquery
    if(e!=''){
        $.post("library/city.php", {ids: e },
       function(data){
         $("#citylist").html(data);
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#regionlist')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="whatever"></option>')
    .val('whatever');

$('#citylist')
    .find('option')
    .remove()
    .end()
    .append('<option value="whatever"></option>')
    .val('whatever');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`$('select').find('option').remove();`

or if you have option groups as well, you can use the same method you use to populate them, `$('select').html('');`

Comment: Didn't work ... Lists appears messed up and not coherent in terms of loading.